Density of similiar Sobolev space
Consider the space of functions defined as,
$$
 D = \{f \in L^p(0,\infty): f \in AC_{loc}(0,\infty) \text{ and } xf'(x) \in L^p(0,\infty)\},
$$
where $AC_{loc}(0,\infty)$ is the set of locally absolute continuous functions on $(0,\infty)$. I want to prove that the set $C_c^\infty(0,\infty)$ is dense in the space $D$ with the norm
$$
\| f \|_D = \|f\|_p + \|xf'(x)\|_p.
$$
My idea
We use the characterizaton of absolute continuous functions and Sobolev spaces, therefore we have that,
$$
  D = \{f \in L^p(0,\infty): f \in W^{1,p}_{loc}(0,\infty) \text{ and } xf'(x) \in L^p(0,\infty)\}.
$$
Therefore as $f \in W^{1,p}_{loc}(0,\infty)$ and as $C_c^\infty(0,\infty)$ is dense on that space with the Sobolev norm we have that exists a sequence $(f_n)_{n\geq0} \subset C_c^\infty(0,\infty)$ such that,
$$
\| f - f_n \|_p + \| f' - f_n' \|_p \to 0, \quad \text{as } n \to \infty
$$
on compact sets $K \subset (0,\infty)$. Therefore we have that
$$
\| f - f_n\|_D \to 0, \quad \text{as } n \to \infty
$$
given $x$ is bounded once we have fixed the compact set $K$. Now I'm struggling how to extend this convergence to the whole space and not just on compact sets.
Other ideas
I have tried using cutoff functions and mollify but I'm not able to make it work either, so if that's the way I'm looking forward to some ideas or references.

I would simply use a mollifier argument, see e.g., Gilbarg Trudinger 7.2 for a standard routine'ish argument on bounded domain. For $(0, \infty)$ the argument carries the same fashion. Okay, the following results are kinda trivial on bounded sets, so essentially the following argument reaches the same one as the author did.
I assume that $p \geq 1$, so certain Sobolev embedding results apply.
First, let $f_{\epsilon}:= \phi_{\epsilon}* f$, then $\|f_\epsilon - f\|_p \to 0$. The only thing that remains to be shown is $\|g - g_{\epsilon}\|_p \to 0$, where $g(x) : = xf'(x)$, and $g_{\epsilon}(x) := xf'_{\epsilon}(x)$. The weak convergence of  $g_{\epsilon} \rightharpoonup g$ can be simply proved by integration by parts: for any $v\in C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R}^+)$
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^+} (xf'(x) - xf'_{\epsilon}(x)) v \,dx 
=  \int_{\mathbb{R}^+} (f'(x) - f'_{\epsilon}(x)) x v \,dx 
\\
= -\int_{\mathbb{R}^+} (f(x) - f_{\epsilon}(x)) (v+xv') \,dx,
$$
then apply Holder, $f_{\epsilon} \to f$ in $\|\cdot\|_p$,and some property of $C^{\infty}_c$ functions.
Next, simply apply a corresponding Sobolev embedding result (Rellich–Kondrachov for example or certain versions of Poincare-Friedrichs inequality) to show that this weak convergence implies the convergence in $\|\cdot\|_p$. You might need to fill out some details about exponents.

EDIT:
My original answer did not answer the question on $(0, +\infty)$, the last part of the argument should be as follows.

Find for any $f\in D$, for any given $\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}^+$, there exists a $g\in D$ but with compact support such that $\|f - g\|_D < \epsilon$.

The argument is quite simple as $\|f\|_D$ is finite, let $I_k := [\frac{1}{k}, k]$ that is compact, and $\|f\|_{D, I_k} = \|\chi_{I_k} f\|_D\nearrow \|f\|_{D}$, thus $\|f - \chi_{I_k} f\|_D =\|f\|_{D, \mathbb{R}^+\backslash I_k} \to 0$.
Now your argument would follow as $f_\epsilon:= \phi_\epsilon*(\chi_{I_k} f)$ with $k := \lfloor 1/\epsilon\rfloor$:
$$
\|f - f_\epsilon\|_D \leq \|f - \chi_{I_k} f\|_D + \|\chi_{I_k} f - \phi_\epsilon*(\chi_{I_k} f)\|_D. 
$$

Thank you so mjuch for your reply, I have a few questions about it.
Q1: You state $ f_\epsilon \to f$ in $L^p$, but this convergence is just on compact sets of $(0,1)$ and not the whole $(0,1)$ how do you obtain the property for $(0,1)$?
Q2: When you say 'some property of $C^\infty_c$functions'' you usea the fact that the function has compact support and its derivative its bounded right?
Q3: I'm not able to find a reference for one dimension of the results that you are talking about.

@ScottishQuestions My bad. I wasn't reading the question carefully enough. Now I edited the answer.
